# Creating a function that opens a file and reads it using ifstream and ofstream but its QT says i didnt declare the function

Tags: c++, function, ifstream, ofstream

Trying to make a function that opens a file using ifstream and offstream but QT compiler tells me my variables are not declared. program is alot longer but its this specific part causing error.

I need to make the function to receive the declared variables in the main code to be able to open the file later on.
Cant Use global variables.
I can make program run without using functions but its a must.

/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: variable or field 'OpenUserFile' declared void

/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: 'load' was not declared in this scope

/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&)
^
/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: 'ReceiptCreator' was not declared in this scope
void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&)
^//////////
/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&)
^////////////
/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: 'Save' was not declared in this scope
void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&)
^/////////
/home/eip/Desktop/atm/ATMFINAL/main.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&)
^

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<iomanip>
  #include<fstream>
  #include<cstdlib>
  #include<ctime>
  using namespace std;






      void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&){

      load.open("id.txt"); // reads id.txt.


       if(load.fail()){ //If file has problems, user receives an error message
        cout<< "Error reading user id" <<endl;
      }

      ofstream& ReceiptCreator,Save; // instruction to create a file.

      ReceiptCreator.open("receipt.txt", ios::app); //prints out output to external .txt file.

      if(ReceiptCreator.fail()){ //if error reading display, error message
      cout<< "Error printing transaction receipt" <<endl;
      }
      }
     int main(){

     time_t C = time(0); // uses computers curren time
     string CT = ctime(&C);// shows user current time



    string account, userName, SocialSec, PassNum, UserBalance,Bankname, FirstName;
    string LastName, AccountNum, SocialNum;//


    int PassFile, PassUser,WithDrawal; // variables for user password
    double InitialBalance,Deposit, CurrentBalance;// variables for aritmethic calculations
    unsigned ATMNUM = 100+rand()%500; // randomizes atm number
    int receipt,process, UI = -99, retry = 1; //
    ofstream ReceiptCreator,Save;
    ifstream load; // starts process to read user information.
    int OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&);

    cout << "Loading data from file..." << endl;
```

Comment: please include the error message in the question. `void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&)` is not correct.

Comment: load, ReceiptCreator and Save not declared in scope
OpenUserFile declared void-

expected primary expression before   ,    token.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy and paste (do not type) the error messages directly in the question.

Comment: c++ is a statically typed language you need to declare the types of the function arguments

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

`void foo(int x){}` Is a function with one argument of type `int`.

`void foo(int){}` Is a function with one unnamed argument of type `int`.

`void OpenUserFile(load&, ReceiptCreator&,Save&){}` Is a function with unnamed arguments of type `load&`, `ReceiptCreateor&` and `Save&`. However those are no types in your code. I'll leave it to you to figure out the correct signature.

You have to fix the errors one by one, because one error can confuse the compiler and trigger other errors. One more problem I can spot now is

```
ofstream& ReceiptCreator,Save;
```

References cannot be not initialized. I suppose this line was just a trial to fix the code, as the names are those of the arguments, then you can remove that line. If not, you need to decide whether to pass the streams as arguments or have them only inside the function, not both.